# How to read packets in Android using Jnetpcap?

Tags: android, packet-capture, jnetpcap

I am working on an Android app where I need to capture the packets. I am using `VpnService` for this purpose. I am able to write the data to a `pcap` file. Next I want to decode the pcap file. I am using `jnetpcap` library version 1.3 for this purpose. I am able to successfully load the library in my application. But when i loop the `pcap` object, it throws an exception. Has anyone used jnetpcap on Android before ? Are there are tutorials or code  example for using jnetpcap in Android, that would be really helpful.